# How to handle locale detecting in next.js application gracefully

Tags: next.js, locale, next-i18next

I am using "next-i18next": "^13.2.2" package for internationalisation in next.js (13.X) application with path based routing.

Now I have a requirement that when a user launches the app URL with appending `lang` parameter then the URL should look like:

`https://my-app.com/path1?lang=de` -> `https://my-app.com/de/path1`.

How can I achieve this gracefully ?
Shall I use rewrites ?
OR Should I use some middleware ? but how ?

I tried to redirect in `getServerSideProps` in `pages/path1` but it did not work, instead it goes into infinite loop.

Also, i tried:

```
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/path1*',
        has: [
          {
            type: 'query',
            key: 'lang',
          },
        ],
        destination: ':lang/path1',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  }

But it goes into infinite loop
```